# How can space and time occur spontaneously?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, spacetime

In the book: "A universe from nothing" by the theoretical physicist Lawrence Krauss he mentions that space and time can occur spontaneously. Unfortunately he does not explain how. So my question is, how can space and time occur spontaneously?

This is the exact quote: "So be it. But what if we are then willing to describe “nothing” as the absence of space and time itself? Is this sufficient? Again, I suspect it would have been . . . at one time. But, as I shall describe, we have learned that space and time can themselves spontaneously appear, so now we are told that even this “nothing” is not really the nothing that matters. " - A universe from nothing - Lawrence Krauss

Edit: The question is not, how can something occur from nothing, just how can time and space start existing from the absence of time and space.

Comment: I think that the question is not well-posed. What do you mean when you say that space and time "occur"? And what do you mean when you say that they occur "spontaneously"?

Comment: Can you quote the exact phrase from the book?

Comment: Having read the book, I can say that Krauss explains everything fairly thoroughly. Can you provide the actual portion of the book that confuses you?

Comment: More exactly, Lawrence Krauss asserted that _the universe arose spontaneously from nothing._ But he said also that _Nothing is not Nothing_

Comment: This is the exact quote: "So be it. But what if we are then willing to describe “nothing” as the absence of space and time itself? Is this sufficient? Again, I suspect it would have been . . . at one time. But, as I shall describe, we have learned that space and time can themselves spontaneously appear, so now we are told that even this “nothing” is not really the nothing that matters. "

Comment: While I did just vote to close this question as unclear what you are asking, I would gladly do the same to Krauss' book, if there was an opportunity. "Nothing" is simply not a well defined physical term and a physicist will not, unless he is in need for money from books sales, waste any time on ill defined concepts. And there you have it... stop reading books like this and get yourself a real physics textbook. That's time and money well spent.

Comment: @CuriousOne My question is not, how can something occur from nothing (a quantum vacum), but how can space and time appear spontanously as he says in the book. This does not imply that there is nothing, just the absence of space and time.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Actually, Krauss pulls a bait & switch with respect to "nothing from nothing". He redefines nothing to be a quantum vacuum, which isn't nothing in the traditional sense of *ex nihilo nihil fit*, it's a quantum field.

Comment: @KyleKanos: Even if we take that bait he doesn't have anything because we know ZERO about the true physical vacuum. Everything we got beyond the standard model, which is basically the equivalent of epicycles, is pure speculation.

Comment: @CuriousOne  : Well, among the "speculations" there are string theories and quantum loop gravity. It is not yet forbiden to think. :-) (as long it is clear that there is no experimental validation, or not yet the practical possibility to mount one).

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET: I am not accusing our valued colleagues of forbidden thinking, I am accusing them of publishing books that pretend to be about physics when, in reality, they are merely their choice of flavor of the intellectual equivalent of ice cream, oh so sweet, but truthfully... no serious food value.

Comment: @Matriz : I don't know this very book, but there are  theories describing the universe as a graph of interaction between its elementary particles (which does not require space and time explicitely), and with a graph you might have occasionaly an approx topological equivalence to continuous varieties (= space and or time, to keep it simple). This process is described as a phase transition of the graph. 
Another cousin view is when particles not yet have mass. Then all go at speed c, so due to contraction no time and space can exist  for those, and make sense only after. For illustration.

Comment: @CuriousOne : well, I agree, seems like basic people are attracted by fancy things about before BB and inside BH and "goddish particles" before really understanding the rule of 3 and getting interest in basic physics :-/ . But the true problem is bad books (when not pseudo-scientists) to answer this curiosity. Or genuine attempt by the good guys but that cannot be understood right without prior knowledge. But is it impossible ? A Richard Feynman would have been able to treat it decently, I guess.

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET: Weinberg wrote an OK book on cosmology with "The First Three Minutes", didn't he? Unfortunately, publishers were demanding ever more ridiculous titles and that has, whether we like it or not, permeated into the content. Even serious theoretical physicists seem to be thinking that they are doing the public a service by writing books about completely unconfirmed models. They need to understand that we aren't asking the public for merely their meager salaries... we are asking it for hundreds of billions for experiments and observatories. The public has a right to the truth.

Comment: They sure shouldn't be presented as "the truth". I have problems also with RG black hole models always presented as "how real back holes are". Still, once this is clear, I think is it useful to give some concepts about the degree of freedom mathematically available and that might (or not) exist for real, as a way to enlarge the reasonning: space could be curved, have many dimensions, velocities might not add and be bounded, space and time might not make sense below some scale or age, and still things keep consistent. But ok, some books play with topologies without pretending it's our universe.

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET Thank you for the interesting input about the topological space on graphs of interaction. Well my question was regarding the statement of Krauss, unfortunately I have very limited knowledge on Physics since I'm a student of pure Mathematics and not in Physics. So I did not see the imprecisness in the statement of Krauss. Could you name some of those theories you described?

Comment: @CuriousOne Unfortunately my Physics knowledge is very limited, since I'm a Mathematics student and not a Physics student, so I didn't knew, that the actual statement of Krauss was so vague (Since he is a theoretical physicist..). I thought there would be a reasonable explanation for his statement and my question like "the existance of time and space is the result of some stochastic process.." (although kind of difficult without time) since the absent of time and space is not the same as nothing.

Comment: There are reasonable explanations for Krauss' statements, but Krauss doesn't have them any more than anybody else. He pretends to have knowledge that is a century, if not centuries away and that is disingenuous. Yes, pretty much every physicist who has thought about these things has some ideas about how all of this fits together, but there is a world of a difference between having ideas and knowing in science. Krauss' book like so many others right now are all jumping ahead from what we know to what we suspect without the slightest shred of evidence.

Answer (score 0):

He meant that

You may think an orange is present in space when it actually doesn't exist.

You imagine coordinates of space which don't exist.

Can you see a dream?

Similarly, here he meant space and time don't exist if you don't imagine them.

But once you think about it, it exist.

Have you seen space and time?

You just imagine it out of nothingness and then next moment you begin to talk about it spontaneously, as if it exist.

If you think something exist, it can spontaneously exist and if you say an orange is an apple, no one in world can false it.